# How do I set a system property before a Mule MMC-deployed app initializes its log4j settings?

Tags: logging, log4j, mule

I want to use a log4j.properties file (it will be named differently) external to my deployed Mule app.  The app is deployed using an MMC server.  In my IDE's test environment, if I set a VM arg `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///c:/esb/etc/log4jconfig/log4j.myApp.properties`, pointing to the external log4j properties file, it works.

But getting that same app to load an external log4j properties file when deployed to the Mule MMC staging environment has not worked yet.

The Maven Surefire plugin will work but that's for the test environment.

I have tried:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>my.property.name</name>
                            <value>my.property.value</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I have also tried:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!--<mainClass>${exec.main-class}</mainClass>-->
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <value>file:///c:/esb/etc/log4jconfig/log4j.myApp.properties</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have tested these configurations in the IDE and also packaged and deployed to the Staging Mule MMC server without success.  I have also tried to feed seven different naming conventions for the property value, which Log4J converts to an URL upon initialization.

We are using log4j-1.2.16.  Looking at the log4j manual at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html, under **Default Initialization Procedure**, I am told that setting the `log4j.configuration` system property will override the location of the log properites file, and it does do that, as I said, when I change the VM args in the IDE tests.

I need a way to get Mule to load that system property before log4j is initialized.

The deployed Mule app in MMC shares the same Mule standalone instance with several other deployed apps, and I do not want to change the log location for all of those apps to the same location.  Each app must have its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding the following bean to your config:

```
<spring:bean id="log4jInitialization"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <spring:property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <spring:property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <spring:property name="arguments">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>file:///c:/esb/etc/log4jconfig/log4j.myApp.properties</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
</spring:bean>
```